# react native Cannot find module 'metro/src/reactNative Transformer'

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

When upgrading to RN 0.59.4 and after a successful build - one can encounter the following error in metro bundler:

`react native Cannot find module 'metro/src/reactNative Transformer`

Answer (score 8):

I think there's an issue with the version of metro packaged with the latest RN Upgrade.
I just installed locally in dev metro `npm install --save-dev metro`, which is the version 0.51.1, and that worked for me.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/293#issuecomment-452779809

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by deleting the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file and then running again **npm install**

Answer (score 5):

I got this error message after upgrading to the latest expo version because I was getting the warning: "The global expo-cli package has been deprecated."

I fixed the error by running "npx expo install --fix".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you at least:

`"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1"`
In dev dependencies in your package.json file

Answer (score 1):

Since you upgraded ReactNative, you must close terminal where `Metro` is running and then re-run `npx react-native start`